# query returning incorrect number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a query because i wanted to segment the scores into high, medium, and low so I could see if these groups compared with another table (that table isn't important here).

When I use the second query it returns ~3000 fewer rows. The only thing I can think is I have a logical error here. It seems like the first and second queries should return essentially the same information but do not.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

```
--query 1 output 12279
select count(*)
from quiz_scores
where item_id between 100 and 200
and score between 0 and 1


--query 2 output 7824 rows
(
select anon_user_id
,title
,'low' as achiever
from quiz_scores
where item_id between 100 and 200
and score between 0 and 0.33
group by anon_user_id
,title

union

select anon_user_id
,title
,'middle'
from quiz_scores
where item_id between 100 and 200
and score between 0.33 and 0.66
group by anon_user_id
,title

union

select anon_user_id
,title
,'high'
from quiz_scores
where item_id between 100 and 200
and score between 0.66 and 1.01
group by anon_user_id
,title
)
```

Comment: Do you have duplicate `anon_user_id` in your table? Because `group by` clause in your 2nd query will negate rows with duplicate `anon_user_id`

Comment: Yes. There can be more than one `anon_user_id` in this table. However when I comment out the `group by anon_user_id, title` it still returns the same number of rows.

Comment: I mean do your table contain 2 or more rows that have the same `anon_user_id`?

Comment: Yes. There can be multiple rows with the same `anon_user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into the reason for the missing records (I think @Doan Cuong got it right), I think the easiest way to get the results you want is using [CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in your select:

```
SELECT   anon_user_id 
        ,title      
        ,(CASE 
           WHEN score  BETWEEN 0 AND 0.33 THEN 'LOW'
           WHEN score  BETWEEN 0.33 AND 0.66 THEN 'Medium'
           WHEN score  BETWEEN 0.66 AND 1.01 THEN 'High'
           ELSE 'Undefiend'
           END) as 'achiever'
FROM   quiz_scores
WHERE item_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200
```

Answer (score 2):

```
--query 1 output 12279
select count(*)
from quiz_scores
where item_id between 100 and 200
and score between 0 and 1
```

This is your 1st query, it doesn't include `group by` clause, therefore, all rows that match the `where` clause will be selected regardless duplicate data

```
--query 2 output 7824 rows
(
select anon_user_id
,title
,'low' as achiever
from quiz_scores
where item_id between 100 and 200
and score between 0 and 0.33
group by anon_user_id
,title

union

select anon_user_id
,title
,'middle'
from quiz_scores
where item_id between 100 and 200
and score between 0.33 and 0.66
group by anon_user_id
,title

union

select anon_user_id
,title
,'high'
from quiz_scores
where item_id between 100 and 200
and score between 0.66 and 1.01
group by anon_user_id
,title
)
```

And this is your 2nd query. Look at each snippet you will see that you're using `group by` clause in each of them. `group by` will ignore rows with duplicate `anon_user_id`, therefore if there're rows with duplicate `anon_user_id` in your table, the row collection which is selected by this query will less than your 1st query.